# How can i get the logs of past months in postgres DB .

Tags: database, postgresql, database-administration, postgresql-9.4, pgadmin

Issue :

Someone has added a junk column in one of my table.I want to figure it out from the logs as when and from where this activity has been performed.

Please Help regarding this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure enable logging in postgresql.conf

```
1.log_destination = 'stderr' #log_destination = 'stderr,csvlog,syslog'  
2.logging_collector = on     #need restart
3.log_directory = 'pg_log'
4.log_file_name = 'postgresql-%Y-%m-%d_%H%M%S.log'
5.log_rotation_age = 1d                 
6.log_rotation_size = 10MB
7.log_min_error_statement = error
8.log_min_duration_statement = 5000 # -1 = disable ; 0 = ALL ; 5000 = 5sec
9.log_line_prefix = '|%m|%r|%d|%u|%e|'
10.log_statment = 'ddl' # 'none' | 'ddl' | 'mod' | 'all'
#prefer 'ddl' because the log output will be 'ddl' and 'query min duration'
```

If you don't enable it, make sure enable it now.

if you don't have log the last attempt is `pg_xlogdump` your xlog file under pg_xlog and look for DDL

Comment: Actually configurations line no. 8 ,9 and 10 are not set. Also i checked in the pg_xlog but i did not find anything named DDL over there. I have a list of 7-8 files over there which i am not able to read.

Comment: pg_xlogdump is your last attempt and cannot reliable if you don't enable logging feature in PostgreSQL. Make sure you already check 'CREATE' or 'DROP' statement. For the future to avoid this mistake. you need to enable logging, full backup weekly (atleast), and installed pg_stat_statements (nice extension to capture all query in database).

Comment: Thank You.Also if someone deletes an from the table manually without running any scripts.Is there any way to find that out as who as executed that.Or the above mentioned are the only solutions for it.

Comment: @AnuragAnand if someone execute query manually. you can capture the query by using `pg_stat_statment extension` :)